# ASP.NET Core MVC project ViewComponent error: "Could not find Invoke or InvokeAsync..."

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am learning how to use a viewcomponent with ASP.NET Core MVC.  I have carefully studied the article at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0

and watched several YouTube videos showing me how to set up the page and the component.  The project compiles without error but when I run it, I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Could not find an 'Invoke' or 'InvokeAsync' method for the view component 'BethanysPieShop.Views.Shared.Components.PieViewComponent'.

I do not know why I am getting this error and I have been scouring the web searching for a description of something awry in my code.  Here is my project folder structure:

[image]

I have the PieViewComponent in the Components folder at the project level.  I also have the component view located in the Views/Shared/Components/Pie/Pie.cshtml.

The view into which I want to use the component has the following invoking code:

```html
<div>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Pie")
</div>
```

Next, the PieViewComponent itself is:

```html
    public class PieViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        IPieRepository PieDB;
        public PieViewComponent(IPieRepository PieRepo)
        {
            PieDB = PieRepo;
        }

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsyc()
        {
            List<Pie> items = await PieDB.GetCheapPiesAsync();  
            PieListViewModel pvlm = new PieListViewModel();
            pvlm.Pies = items;
            pvlm.CurrentCategory = "Cheap Pies";

            return View("Pie", pvlm);
        }

    }
```

The PieViewListModel contains a list of pie objects and a string (the name).

And finally, the view component itself is:

```html
@model PieListViewModel

    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach (Pie p in Model.Pies)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item">p.Name</li>
        }
    </ul>
```

I do not know why the runtime cannot find the InvokeAsync method.  I think I have built the project with all of the conventions for file placement within the project's folder structure.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Move your file containing  PieViewComponent  class to Controllers folder and add attribute to the view component

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "Pie")]
public class PieViewComponent : ViewComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change the Pie.cshtml file name to Default.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

Under `public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsyc()` you spelled `Async` incorrectly